# ReferenceError: xmlHttpRequest is not defined this is because of some id used in footer links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

Basically i want to insert these values to my db and via ajax so that pag will not refresh and can insert every record. i am using wordpress pages custom template so thats why company-update/?update=

My form and java script please tell me whats the problem

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function ram(){
  var xmlhttp= new xmlHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET","company-update/?update="+document.getElementById("update1").value+"&customer_id="+document.getElementById("customerid1").value+"&customer_name="+document.getElementById("customer_name1").value+"&pass="+document.getElementById("pass1").value+"&agree="+document.getElementById("agree1").value,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);

document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

}
</script>
```

```html
<section>


  <h4>Type Your Updated Response There</h4>
  <br/><br/>
  <form action="" id="fscf_for" method="post">
  <ul class="input-list style-1 clearfix">
    <li>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Type Your Updated Response There" name="update1" id="update1" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="text" name="customer_id1" id="customerid1" value="<?php echo $search;?>">
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="hidden" name="customer_name1" id="customer_name1" value="<?php echo $r->Name;?>">
    </li> 
    <li>
      <input type="textarea" name="pass1" id="pass1" value="">
    </li>
    <li>
    <label>Mail : YES</label>
<input type='radio' name='agree1' id=='agree1' value='yes' />
<label>NO</label>
<input type='radio' name='agree1' id='agree1' value='no' checked="checked" />
 </li> </ul><br/>
  <input type="button" id="fscf_submi" style="cursor:pointer; margin:0;" value="Update" onclick=" ram();" /> 
  <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><div id="d1"></div></td></tr>
</form>
</section>`
```

showing this kind of error at everyclick on button

in console of firebug so it looks these ids of menus is messing up with me. so kindly help me to run this guys

ReferenceError: xmlHttpRequest

```html
<li id="menu-item-1083" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1083"><a href="http://www.sunwally.co.in/calendars/">Calendars</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1084" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1084"><a href="http://www.sunwally.co.in/caps/">Caps</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1085" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1085"><a href="http://www.sunwally.co.in/collar-neck-t-shirts/">Collar Neck T-Shirts</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1086" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1086"><a href="http://www.sunwally.co.in/collage-activity-uniforms/">College Activity Uniforms</a></li>
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Note that JS is case sensitive - it should be `new XMLHttpRequest()`

Comment: Thanks Yes you guys are right i forgot this thing but as when i am changing the radio button state from no to yes or in second insertion yes to no it not takes in that way else insertion is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive therefore it will throw the undefined error (as it doesn't exist how you have written it) you need to do

```
new XMLHttpRequest()
```

Comment: Thanks Yes you guys are right i forgot this thing but as when i am changing the radio button state from no to yes or in second insertion yes to no it not takes in that way else insertion is working

Comment: I want to know also how i can send correct value of radio button when i will change state from no to yes it always sends no as value im beginner so please give me some brief answer